# What is %InstallRoot% in Visual Studio msdn documentation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, directory, msdn

[Some MSDN articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255821%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) refer to %InstallRoot%. What is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the root directory of Visual Studio installation. For VS2012 it could be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\` for example.